# How can I stop a VM guest from being able to access the host's LAN (and the host itself)?

Tags: networking, virtualization

I'm running an Ubuntu 22.04 host with a 22.04 guest (using Multipass). Currently, the guest can access the LAN and the host. How can I prevent the guest from accessing the LAN, while still allowing it to connect to the internet?

I only have access to the host by SSH.

Comment: You can add rules to the `FORWARD` chain that prohibit traffic originating from your virtual machine and destined for the local network. You can add rules to the `INPUT` chain to prevent access to the host itself.

Comment: well a more common sense would in my mind to use vlan

Answer (score 0):

I've added a rule to the FORWARD chain to block access to the LAN:

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -s <VM-subnet> -d <LAN-subnet> -j DROP
```

and rules to the INPUT chain to block access to the host:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d <VM-subnet> -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s <VM-subnet> -j DROP
```